# Помогите улучшить таймер. Работает только когда пользователь на странице

Tags: javascript, события, таймер

Прошу помощи в интеграции функции проверки на странице ли пользователь и если нет то  таймер стоит и ждет когда пользователь зайдет.
    Сам таймер:

```
  function startClock() {
  if (vtime == stattime) {
    document.getElementById('blockwait').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('blocktimer').style.display = '';
  }
  if (vtime >= 0) {
    document.forms['frm'].clock.value = vtime;
    vtime--;
    tm = setTimeout("startClock(0)", 1000);
  } else {
    if (tm)
      clearTimeout(tm);

  }
}

//Вот какой таймер я нашел где это реализовано:

mya = true; //по умолчанию вкладка активна
a = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  if (!mya) return; //если не активная вкладка, ничего не делаем
  a++; //счетчик секунд
  document.querySelector('.onlineuser').innerHTML = a;
}, 1000)
window.onfocus = function() {
  mya = true;
} //пользователь на вкладке сайте
window.onblur = function() {
  mya = false;
} //пользователь закрыл вкладку или переключил на другую
```

Как можно реализовать проверку на вкладке ли пользователь? Не могу перенести со второй функции в первую - не работает.

Плюс у меня еще есть ***php переменная $add_bonus = 1 или 0;*** Так вот когда она равна  ***1*** то таймер останавливается при переходе на другую вкладку, а когда на 0 то продолжает идти.

Comment: Есть событие перехода на другую вкладку `visibilitychange`

Answer (score 0):

Если делать с помощью API то вот функция:

```js
var handleChange = function handleChange() {
  if (!document.hidden) {
  } else {
  }
};

window.addEventListener('visibilitychange', handleChange);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

как это совместить с моей функцией:

```
function startClock() {
if (vtime == stattime) {
    document.getElementById('blockwait').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('blocktimer').style.display = '';
}
if (vtime >= 0) {
    document.forms['frm'].clock.value = vtime;
    vtime ++;
    tm = setTimeout("startClock(0)", 1000);
} else {
    if (tm)
        clearTimeout(tm);
    nextstep(0, cnt);
}
}
```

Чтобы только исполнение таймера останавливалось когда я на другой вкладке